# Visual Studio Code and starting tasks from /.vscode/task,json: How to force them staring from CMD and not Powershell?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, cmd, vscode-tasks

I have the below tasks.json and  it works fine, except that they are run from Powershell. And the browser-sync task gives an error: "browser-sync : File C:\Users\marti\AppData\Roaming\npm\browser-sync.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system."

It works fine if tasks are run from Cmd terminal instead. How can I make them start from there? I have set Cmd as default terminal in VS.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Start watching scss and js",
            "type": "cmd",
            "command": "npm start",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new"
            },
            "runOptions": { "runOn": "folderOpen" }
        },
        {
            "label": "Start browser-sync",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "browser-sync start --proxy \"localhost:5829\" --files \"css/*.css\"",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new"
            },
            "runOptions": { "runOn": "folderOpen" }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: As a one-time action, assuming your [PowerShell execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) isn't set via GPOs (Group Policy), run, for instance,  `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUsers RemoteSigned` from a PowerShell session. If you have admin privileges and want to set it for _all users_, use `-Scope AllUsers`, from an elevated PowerShell session.

Comment: I get this error (have opened PS as admin): 

PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope AllUsers RemoteSigned
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Cannot bind parameter 'Scope'. Cannot convert value "AllUsers" to type
"Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicyScope". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name AllUsers to a valid
enumerator name. Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:
Process, CurrentUser, LocalMachine, UserPolicy, MachinePolicy"

Comment: Sorry, I meant `-Scope LocalMachine` (all users) or `-Scope CurrentUser` - see [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy)